# Cannot start tomcat on port when using PostConstruct anotation to watch mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, watch

1. MySolutionApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySolutionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySolutionApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

2. IndexTrigger.java

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   // Get database
   MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName.toString());

   // Watch
   MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor = database.watch(
                    Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(Filters.in("operationType", 
                        Arrays.asList(
                        rules.INSERT.ACTION, 
                        rules.UPDATE.ACTION, 
                        rules.REPLACE.ACTION,
                        rules.DELETE.ACTION
                    ))))).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).iterator();
            
                // Loop
                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    ChangeStreamDocument<Document> fullDocument = cursor.next();
                    String collectionName = fullDocument.getNamespace().getCollectionName();
                    String serviceName = covertCollectionNameToTriggerService(collectionName);
                    try {
                        String classNameTriggerService = NAMESPACE_SERVICE.concat(serviceName);
                        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classNameTriggerService);
                        
                        // Check exists service
                        if (clazz != null) {
    
                            // Set data
                            conn.setFullDocument(fullDocument);
    
                            // create bean
    //                        applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    printBlock.apply(fullDocument);
                }
}
```

3. Image
   [image]

I cannot open port. When code run to `database.watch`. Progress is opening connection mongodb and not run more ( next must "Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''". But No.) ( image above ). I sure about my coding working. I tested and working. It's "watched changer stream mongodb" is ok. But i want open port to run web application with java spring. Please help me.
**Same issue:** [Spring boot + Mongo listener , does not allow tomcat to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796310/spring-boot-mongo-listener-does-not-allow-tomcat-to-start)